# DBeaver Error 1146 (42S02) on SQL database restore- Table 'acumatica.AUNotification' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, dbeaver

I am trying to restore a database dump from a file for an online SQL course I'm taking into DBeaver. When I restore it, however, it runs for a little bit and then I get the error message

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 4037: Table 'acumatica.AUNotification' doesn't exist
```

I've tried:

1. Manually dropping the table via the mysql command line, and then copying the CREATE TABLE statement from the .sql dump file to manually create it.
2. Reinstalling SQL
3. Using `sqldump` except I think it just dumped the existing file.
4. Doing `mysql -u root -p --database=acumatica < dump-acumaticadb-201903141403.sql`

All of my attempts to restore it work for a little bit- when I refresh the database in DBeaver, it shows the table aunotification and all preceding tables. There are no subsequent tables. Also, I'm using the utf8mb4 charset, so I don't think that's the issue.

I would really appreciate any help someone could give- the other threads I've found online have not helped me.

Here's the full error message in DBeaver after restoring the database:

```
/usr/bin/mysql --host=localhost --port=3306 -u root acumatica
Task 'MySQL script' started at Sun Mar 22 11:43:56 PDT 2020
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 4037: Table 'acumatica.AUNotification' doesn't exist
Task 'MySQL script' finished at Sun Mar 22 11:44:01 PDT 2020
2020-03-22 11:44:01.556 - IO error: Process failed (exit code = 1). See error log.
2020-03-22 11:44:01.557 - java.io.IOException: Process failed (exit code = 1). See error log.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.executeProcess(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:182)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.doExecute(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:237)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.tasks.nativetool.AbstractNativeToolHandler.lambda$0(AbstractNativeToolHandler.java:52)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.runtime.RunnableContextDelegate.lambda$0(RunnableContextDelegate.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KNh1.jpg error log screenshot

https://pastebin.com/KfCRW2G2 create statements and surrounding file

Comment: Does it show the table 'aunotification' or the table 'AUNotification'?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes- the dbeaver Tables folder for the acumatica database shows 'aunotification' at the bottom of the list. It is the last table present.

Comment: The error log and the create table statement would have allowed something more than wild guesses.

Comment: Question has been closed as "off-topic".   When I read what's "on-topic", the first line says: "Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore".  It would have been interesting to find out why the results of a mysqldump cannot be restored.

Comment: On what OS was the dump created?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I do not know- in the online class it was merely provided as a download, with no information regarding its creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The create table may not have used quotes around the table name, while a reference to it does.

Unless lower_case_table_names=1 is set upon database creation, the case of the tablenames has to be respected when quoted.

Comment: All references (from my quick skim of the error line area) to aunotification in the dump file are surrounded with backticks

Comment: But what about the create statement?  And do they use the same case?

Comment: The create statement was fine! There were some references later within /*! statements that used AUNotification instead of aunotification. I replaced them with lower case instances and it worked- those tables were created. However, the error reappears some 500 lines later. Since this file is way more than 4000 lines long (which I'm very sure it is), how would I automate the process to fix these instances of unmatched case for table names? And thank you so much for responding, I'm really grateful.

Comment: An editor like vim would do the job in a couple of seconds.  Line editors too.  Do you have experience with any of those?   What is your OS?  Did the create statement contain quotes?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu. I'm relatively inexperienced with vim, although I've read some introductory material- how could I make it so that all the different words change to lowercase? For example, I'm now experiencing my issue with the table EPLoginType, which is of course a different string than AUNotification. This is ocurring several thousands of lines of code away from my initial problem. The create statements contain backticks for the table names.

Comment: Please add an example from a create statement and a reference to it, to your original question.  I already asked for the error log too.

Comment: Ok, my apologies. I added a screenshot to the error log in dbeaver and a link to a segment of code where the issue corresponds. They're at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: No, that is a screenshot of dbeaver that tells you to "See error log". I would think there is a log somewhere on the server.  But it is of no consequence, the dump file is a shambles.   You could try to create a new database with lower_case_table_names=1.   Otherwise, use 'vi' to edit the dump and enter ":%s/`EPLoginType`/`eplogintype`/g" (without the double quotes). You may not see it, but there are no spaces, they should be backquotes.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the help again. I think I've got it!

Comment: Will you try with the lowercase parameter?

Comment: Yes!!! It took a bunch of trial and error with the lower_case_table_names, since it's hard to change that value on ubuntu but it worked. Thank you for helping so much! I have the full database restored.

Comment: My pleasure.  Would you mind accepting my answer?  I believe the parameter can only be set when you create the database.